# Why Mui button styles are not applying, when I set it to contained?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

After upgrading to the latest version of MUI, I have noticed that MUI buttons are not working correctly when I set the variant to `contained`.

```
      <div className="flex">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
          Add
        </Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" fullWidth>
          remove
        </Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" fullWidth>
          remove
        </Button>
      </div>
```

As you can see in the example, there is nothing wrong with my theme colors as the `outlined` button works as expected.

I am also using tailwindcss, but I don't think that should be related to it at all.

Edit:

After inspecting the button element, I see that `@tailwind base` causes this issue.

What do I do in this case, I think I need `@tailwind base` for my tailwind utilities?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the behavior. I suspect you have CSS somewhere that is controlling the background color of the button (overriding the default MUI CSS for contained buttons). You should be able to inspect the button with developer tools to see where the CSS for the white background is coming from.

Comment: @RyanCogswell after inspecting element, I found that `@tailwind base` is what's causing this issue, but I think I need this for my tailwind utilities, what can I do about it?

Comment: Please review MUI's [Tailwind CSS interoperability guide](https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a matter of style clashing between MUI components and Tailwind's preflights. These [interoperability settings](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css) specified by the MUI team may hold the answer to the issue.

The main actions are to edit your `tailwing.config` file and include the following:

```
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    // items to watch
  ],

  /* ==== add this === */
  important: '#root',
  /* ==== ======== === */

  theme: {
    // theme settings
  },

  /* ==== and this === */
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  /* ==== ====== === */

  plugins: [],
};
```

The `important` setting as mentioned in the docs:

> helps ensure that the deeper elements can always be customized using Tailwind's utility classes.

This becomes important when dealing with deeply nested structures. Note that the `#root` points to the app wrapper, in this case, an app created using the `CRA` - create-react-app - tool.

The second addition disables tailwinds `preflight` style so that MUI's preflight is used instead.

Ooh, and you may need to restart your server in cases of React, Next, Angular etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35579991)

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.